# Update app on Heroku with connection error

Tags: java, heroku, heroku-postgres

Hello I'm trying to update my app on heroku. When I build my app this error appears:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3042) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at pl.jawegiel.util.DbUtil.getConnection(DbUtil.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at pl.jawegiel.dao.UsersBasicInfoDao.<init>(UsersBasicInfoDao.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at pl.jawegiel.dao.UsersDao.<init>(UsersDao.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at pl.jawegiel.listener.SessionListener.<init>(SessionListener.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

where my DbUtil class looks like this:

```
public class DbUtil {

public static Connection getConnection() throws URISyntaxException, SQLException {
    URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));

    String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
    String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + ':' + dbUri.getPort() + dbUri.getPath();

    return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password);
}

}
```

I did exactly as Heroku tutorial says but in vain. Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this line

```
System.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
```

The program could not find the system environment variable on heroku.

You will have to add the environment variable value using config var or set define database url inside the class and use it.

Comment: How to do this? Is it necessary to deploy?

Comment: There is an option to add config vars on heroku there you can add it.

Comment: I don't know how to do that it's my first time :(

Comment: Under the settings page for the app, you can edit your [Config Vars](https://i.imgur.com/BRJppH4.png).  https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<app-id>/settings

Comment: It is already set. I copied this value (String) instead of System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"). Is it good solution?

Comment: If you are not using any other database then it won't be a problem. But using the environment variable is the good process. S That if in in future the database url changes we don't have to change it in our program, we have to only change the environment variable.

Comment: Please note that `DATABASE_URL` could change when Heroku has to replace your database (i.e. because the underlying machine failed, etc.). Heroku will then update your `DATABASE_URL` and restart your app. If you don't use the env var, but a static string, your app will probably stop working. I heavily recommend figuring out why you can't access the env var instead of copying the value. BTW: You can use `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` which is already in the correct format so you can use it with `DriverManager.getConnection` directly.